# Table values are not showing - ASP.net

Tags: c#, asp.net, asp.net-mvc, entity-framework, asp.net-mvc-4

This might be a dumb question as I'm new to the MVC pattern in asp.net.
I'm trying to access to the value in my database but the values don't get rendered
on the view page.

here's the code I have written.

code for the "Resturant" model:

```
using System;
using System.Collections.Generic;
using System.ComponentModel.DataAnnotations.Schema;
using System.Linq;
using System.Web;

namespace OdetoFood.Models
{
    [Table("Resturants")]
    public class Resturant
    {
        public int Id { get; set; }
        public string Name { get; set; }
        public string City { get; set; }
        public string Country { get; set; }
        public ICollection<ResturantReviews> Reviews { get; set; }

    }
}
```

here's my DbContext model:

```
using System;
using System.Collections.Generic;
using System.Data.Entity;
using System.Linq;
using System.Web;

namespace OdetoFood.Models
{
    public class OdeToFoodDb : DbContext

    {
        public DbSet<Resturant> Resturants { get; set; }
        public DbSet<ResturantReviews> Reviews { get; set; }
    }
}
```

Code for the controller class:

```
public class HomeController : Controller
    {
        OdeToFoodDb _db = new OdeToFoodDb();
        public ActionResult Index()
        {
            var model = _db.Resturants.ToList();

            return View(model);
        }
```

and here's the view that should be displaying the values:

```
@model IEnumerable<OdetoFood.Models.Resturant>

@{
    ViewBag.Title = "Home Page";
 }


@foreach (var item in Model)
{
    <h3>@item.Name</h3>
    <div>@item.City, @item.Country</div>
    <div>@item.Id</div>
}
```

the connection string in Web.config is setup like this:

```
  <connectionStrings>
    <add name="DefaultConnection" connectionString="Data Source=(LocalDb)\v11.0;AttachDbFilename=|DataDirectory|\aspnet-OdetoFood-20150611025411.mdf;Initial Catalog=aspnet-OdetoFood-20150611025411;Integrated Security=True"
      providerName="System.Data.SqlClient" />
  </connectionStrings>
```

What am I doing wrong here?

Comment: I'm familiar with that tutorial. Are you getting an error or just no data? Did you Seed() the database?

Comment: I'm not getting any errors. The view page renders fine but the values don't get displayed. How do you do Seed()?

Comment: If your doing the pluralsight video there is an earlier section on database migrations. If you're not, you can either populate manually or create a migration.

Comment: Does `var model = _db.Resturants.ToList();` return any items?

Comment: I got it to work now. The issue was as Steve rightly pointed out, I had to enable Auto migration so it wasn't pointing to the right database.

Answer (score 0):

This would be the seed method for that project:

```
protected override void Seed(OdeToFood.Models.OdeToFoodDb context)

    {

        context.Restaurants.AddOrUpdate(r => r.Name,

            new Restaurant { Name = "Sabatino's", City = "Baltimore", Country = "USA" },

            new Restaurant { Name = "Great Lake", City = "Chicago", Country = "USA" },

            new Restaurant

            {

                Name = "Smaka",

                City = "Gothenburg",

                Country = "Sweden",

                Reviews =

                 new List<RestaurantReview>{

                      new RestaurantReview{ Rating = 9, Body="Great Food!" }

                  }

            });

    }
```